# Joomla Migration

Tags: joomla1.5

I successfully migrate Joomla from 1.0 to 1.5.0 stable, while searching for migrate 1.5.0 to 1.5.25 I found [Upgrading 1.5 from an existing 1.5x version](http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_1.5_from_an_existing_1.5x_version) and download [Joomla_1.5.0_to_1.5.25-Stable-Patch_Package.zip](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/frs/?action=FrsReleaseBrowse&frs_package_id=6159)
but what will be the next step I have to do..? There they say that unzip the Patch package but don't guide what to do after unzip? How to Migrate **Joomla 1.5.0** db & contents to **Joomal 1.5.25**?

I am doing all of this on my local with **wamp-2.0.58** and **php-4.4.9**

Please guide me I stuck and lot of time have already be wasted. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I backup & just paste the unzip stuff in joomla 1.5.0 folder.